# How to install a Nokia emulator in Sun Java ME IDE?

Tags: java-me

How to install a Nokia emulator in Sun Java ME IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and install the [Nokia SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/Platforms/Series_40_Platform_SDKs/) (I assume you aim at S40).

See more instructions [here](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?p=27704&postcount=2)

Comment: Mac OS developers would probably care to note that at this stage, the Early Access Java ME SDK 3.0 as far as I know, does not yet support the Nokia Emulator (and may never, unless Nokia decide to provide an emulator for Mac OS). Here's hoping!